# Iterating through a list and lines in text file at the same rate using python?

Tags: python, list, file-io, iteration

So I have a homework assignment I asked in another post, but was not very detailed therefore to my own fault did not get the answer I was looking for.  What I need to do is open a structured text file where each line of the file pertains to a specific category.  Though the categories and order will not change, the number of times they are repeated might.  My job is to take each line (ignoring the first 2) and add an XML tag to that line.  To do this I have come up with a list with the string names of the categories.  The problem I am having is that I can't figure out how to iterate through the list of categories at the same rate as the lines of text in the file.

for example:

if my text file is:

```
peas
carrots
broccoli
beans
```

and my list is

```
tagList=["apples","oranges","bananas","pears"]
```

then I keep getting:

```
<apples>peas</apples>
<oranges>peas</oranges>
<bananas>peas</bananas>
<pears>peas</pears>
<apples>carrots</apples>
<oranges>carrots</oranges>
<bananas>carrots</bananas>
<pears>carrots</pears>
ect....
```

instead of just

```
<apples>peas</apples>
<oranges>carrots</oranges>
<bananas>broccoli</bananas>
<pears>beans</pears>
```

I'm under the impression i need a nested for loop so I have something like this.

```
for line in file:
    for x in tagList:
        outputFile.write("<"+x+">"+line+"</"+x+">\n")
```

I understand exactly why things are coming out the way that they are, I just feel lost on how to fix it.  I have found other posts on iterating through 2 lists at the same rate,  but can't seem to find anything on iterating through lines in a file and a list at the same rate.   Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the policy is here about answering homework, but I'll explain what your code is doing in case that helps:

It's working exactly the way you coded it.

You nested a for loop (tagList within file).

So what you're essentially doing is going through file and if there are 4 items, at each point (1-4) you are looping again going through tagList (which has 4 items).

So at the first step, you got peas (from file), but before you can output it, you go into another for loop (tagList) and once you're in there, you'll output "peas".

Then the second for loop is going to go through again an additional 3 times and you'll get a total of 4 "peas". Once that iteration is done, you're back at the first for loop and move to the next element which this time would output carrots.

Hope that explains what you're doing here.

Comment: Stack Overflow Meta on homework: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Answer (score 1):

Unutbu is correct - zip is the easiest to use here.

```
>>> lista = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>> listb = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> for a, b in zip(lista, listb):
    print a, b

a 1
b 2
c 3
d 4
```

A nested for loop looks like this, and will essentially multiply your lists together - I don't think this is what you want here.

```
>>> for a in lista:
    for b in listb:
        print a, b


a 1
a 2
a 3
a 4
b 1
b 2
...
```

Another method is to use a list index, although since Python has the zip function, you'd be better off using that.

```
>>> for i in range(4):
    print lista[i], listb[i]


a 1
b 2
c 3
d 4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    python 3.2
    list comprehension

    >>> [["<"+v+">"+i+"</"+v+">"] for i in st for v in tag]
```